# Computer shutting down by itself

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, shutdown, ubuntu-16.04

My computer is shutting down by itself, and i don't know what is causing the problem. Here is my case:

**Before**

Last sunday there it was a storm and we had a power shortage, when the computer was on. When electricity came back i used the computer normally during the week. It didn't show any problems. Friday i left for my hometown and did something i never do (unplugging my computer from power) and left it like that until today (sunday). As far as i know there it weren't any power shortage during the weekend i was out (and my computer wasn't plugged anyway).

**The problem**

So, when i came back (today) i turned on the computer, it worked properly for a few minutes and then it shutted down for no apparent reason. I rebooted it and used for another time then it shutted down again.

**Investigation**
1. My first tought was the temperature. I opened the CPU and 'cleaned' the vents (they were already clean since i last cleaned my computer 2 months ago) and putted it back. Didn't work. I was using ubuntu so i did a few things in the command line and started monitoring the temperature, voltages, and so on. None of them seemed abnormal. The temperature stood around 47-48 degrees celsius all the time. So, i really don't think that overheating is the problem here, nor voltage.

2. My tought, then, was that this could be a corrupt OS installation (highly unlikely, anyway) so i started with Windows (i have a dualboot) and it also shutted down.

**It shuts down abruptly, with no warnings**

3. I suspected that it could be something related to power supply, so i made shure that the cables were properly connected. They are, but that doesn't seems to be the problem.

The time before shut down seems to be completely random. Sometimes it stays on for like 1 hour or so, and sometimes it shuts down in 10 or 15 minutes. The activities i do on the computer doesn't seem to be causing the problem, since it shut down after 10 minutes in homescreen, and after rebooting i was able to watch a few videos and it didn't shutted down.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Id say your issue is power related (most black-screen shutdowns are), and may be the result of damage from the storm. First, I'd try to confirm that you are getting clean power from the wall. if you have the money, dropping a UPS inline will tell you, and its a good investment either way.  if the problem persists, then you have an issue with either your power supply or your motherboard (or much less likely, your vidcard or CPU; basically high power-draw devices).

Comment: Did your computer turned off suddenly, without proper shutdown, last Sunday?

Comment: BTW shutting itself down, is a feature in motherboard, to protect precious components. Reasons could be damaged heatsink, damaged PSU etc. Please also mention after what amount of time it shuts down itself.

Comment: @Aman Yes, it was. But i find it weird that the week after the storm the computer worked perfectly. Now, a week later, the problem showed up.

Comment: By "It was" i meant: it was turned on when we had the power shortage.

Comment: @Aman as for your question, i stated in my question that the time before shutdown is random. Sometimes 1 hour, sometimes 30 seconds.

Comment: You have to open the case and use the computer and see when shutting down, did the PSU is working properly or not. Also check whether the thermal paste is proper or it is burnt off? One another thing also, change the plug in which you are currently adding your PC plug.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the plug and it seems to have worked. I'll leave the question open, in case of the problem returning or something.